# Maven archetypes dynamic folder not properly generated

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

I've Maven Archetype with folder a structure which I want to be `src/main/java/__package__/model`.

So I filled that structure while defining. The issue is that maven archetype generates this resulting structure:
`src/main/java/com.myapp/model` (notice the dot in place of the expected folder separator :( ).

Anyone's got an idea on how to resolve?

I also tried

```
<directory>src/main/java/__package__/model</directory>
```

On my fileset definition, but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance, Charlie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `__packageInPathFormat__` instead.

Comment: It's the first time I hear about this property, neither google gave me info about this. Must I replace `__package__` by `__packageInPathInfo__` ?

Comment: Sorry, the correct syntax is __packageInPathFormat__. Use this.